# List index out of range: I don't know how to solve it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know how to solve this error

there's the code:

```
     for i in range(len(oldsize)):   
          if hitboxx[0] == oldsize[i+1]:       #list index out of range
               print("Some TEXTeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
          print(i)
          print(oldsize[i])
```

Comment: Once you get to the last item in your list `oldsize`, the line `if hitboxx[0] == oldsize[i+1]:` is trying to compare to the next item which doesn't exist because you are already at the last one.

Comment: The error basically hits during the last iteration. For example if your oldsize has 5 elements they are indexed from  0 to 4. But your second line calls for index 5 ( During last iteration) which is non existent. Hence the error

Answer (score 1):

You type for loop in below format
    for i, j in enumerate(oldsize[1:]):

## where i is index and j is the value at that index this code will fetch result from second value leaving the first one as we define it to take value from index 1 from oldsize list

Answer (score 0):

Just add a size check before indexing for `i+1` in case `i` is at the last item of `oldsize`, which means `i+1` will be the "one past the last" item, which doesn't exist.

```
 for i in range(len(oldsize)):   
      if i + 1 < len(oldsize) and hitboxx[0] == oldsize[i+1]:
           print("Some TEXTeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
      print(i)
      print(oldsize[i])
```

Alternatively, you can cache the first item of oldsize and compare the item with the item in the for loop, then update the cached item to advance with the for loop. Also, you can use `enumerate` to access both index and item at that index.

```
lastItem = oldsize[0]
for i, item in enumerate(oldsize[1:]):    # iterate starting with the second element
    if hitboxx[0] == item:
        print("Some TEXTeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
    print(i)
    print(lastItem)
    lastItem = item
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't specify what do i want to do. i wanna make a snake game, and this must be the functions that checks if the snake touches itself.

i'm trying to do this with coordinates placed in lists (like oldsize and hitboxx)

but with this code it'll print forever the debug text "Some textee..".

how to solve it? i'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your list contains `5` elements. Its length will be `5`, and its indexes from `0` to `4`.

```
for i in range(len(oldsize)):
```

This will check for indexes `i` from `0` to `4`. If you ask for element `i+1`, the last `i+1` will be `5`, which is out of range.

To remediate to that, do not iterate further than `i=3`. You'll want to do this :

```
for i in range(len(oldsize) - 1):
```